# Replace NAs with mean for a particular day in time series R

Tags: r, time-series, na

Given the time series below I would like to replace the `NAs` for a `specific day` using the `average` of all values for that `day` in the time series.

For example, if 1997-04-01 has a missing value, I would like to replace that NA with the average value of all April 01s in the time series.

Any thoughts are welcome.

```
     structure(list(Date = c("1997-1-1", "1997-1-2", "1997-1-3", "1997-1-4", 
"1997-1-5", "1997-1-6", "1997-1-7", "1997-1-8", "1997-1-9", "1997-1-10", 
"1997-1-11", "1997-1-12", "1997-1-13", "1997-1-14", "1997-1-15", 
"1997-1-16", "1997-1-17", "1997-1-18", "1997-1-19", "1997-1-20", 
"1997-1-21", "1997-1-22", "1997-1-23", "1997-1-24", "1997-1-25", 
"1997-1-26", "1997-1-27", "1997-1-28", "1997-1-29", "1997-1-30", 
"1997-1-31", "1997-2-1", "1997-2-2", "1997-2-3", "1997-2-4", 
"1997-2-5", "1997-2-6", "1997-2-7", "1997-2-8", "1997-2-9", "1997-2-10", 
"1997-2-11", "1997-2-12", "1997-2-13", "1997-2-14", "1997-2-15", 
"1997-2-16", "1997-2-17", "1997-2-18", "1997-2-19", "1997-2-20", 
"1997-2-21", "1997-2-22", "1997-2-23", "1997-2-24", "1997-2-25", 
"1997-2-26", "1997-2-27", "1997-2-28", "1997-3-1", "1997-3-2", 
"1997-3-3", "1997-3-4", "1997-3-5", "1997-3-6", "1997-3-7", "1997-3-8", 
"1997-3-9", "1997-3-10", "1997-3-11", "1997-3-12", "1997-3-13", 
"1997-3-14", "1997-3-15", "1997-3-16", "1997-3-17", "1997-3-18", 
"1997-3-19", "1997-3-20", "1997-3-21", "1997-3-22", "1997-3-23", 
"1997-3-24", "1997-3-25", "1997-3-26", "1997-3-27", "1997-3-28", 
"1997-3-29", "1997-3-30", "1997-3-31", "1997-4-1", "1997-4-2", 
"1997-4-3", "1997-4-4", "1997-4-5", "1997-4-6", "1997-4-7", "1997-4-8", 
"1997-4-9", "1997-4-10", "1997-4-11", "1997-4-12", "1997-4-13", 
"1997-4-14", "1997-4-15", "1997-4-16", "1997-4-17", "1997-4-18", 
"1997-4-19", "1997-4-20", "1997-4-21", "1997-4-22", "1997-4-23", 
"1997-4-24", "1997-4-25", "1997-4-26", "1997-4-27", "1997-4-28", 
"1997-4-29", "1997-4-30", "1997-5-1", "1997-5-2", "1997-5-3", 
"1997-5-4", "1997-5-5", "1997-5-6", "1997-5-7", "1997-5-8", "1997-5-9", 
"1997-5-10", "1997-5-11", "1997-5-12", "1997-5-13", "1997-5-14", 
"1997-5-15", "1997-5-16", "1997-5-17", "1997-5-18", "1997-5-19", 
"1997-5-20", "1997-5-21", "1997-5-22", "1997-5-23", "1997-5-24", 
"1997-5-25", "1997-5-26", "1997-5-27", "1997-5-28", "1997-5-29", 
"1997-5-30", "1997-5-31", "1997-6-1", "1997-6-2", "1997-6-3", 
"1997-6-4", "1997-6-5", "1997-6-6", "1997-6-7", "1997-6-8", "1997-6-9", 
"1997-6-10", "1997-6-11", "1997-6-12", "1997-6-13", "1997-6-14", 
"1997-6-15", "1997-6-16", "1997-6-17", "1997-6-18", "1997-6-19", 
"1997-6-20", "1997-6-21", "1997-6-22", "1997-6-23", "1997-6-24", 
"1997-6-25", "1997-6-26", "1997-6-27", "1997-6-28", "1997-6-29", 
"1997-6-30", "1997-7-1", "1997-7-2", "1997-7-3", "1997-7-4", 
"1997-7-5", "1997-7-6", "1997-7-7", "1997-7-8", "1997-7-9", "1997-7-10", 
"1997-7-11", "1997-7-12", "1997-7-13", "1997-7-14", "1997-7-15", 
"1997-7-16", "1997-7-17", "1997-7-18", "1997-7-19", "1997-7-20", 
"1997-7-21", "1997-7-22", "1997-7-23", "1997-7-24", "1997-7-25", 
"1997-7-26", "1997-7-27", "1997-7-28", "1997-7-29", "1997-7-30", 
"1997-7-31", "1997-8-1", "1997-8-2", "1997-8-3", "1997-8-4", 
"1997-8-5", "1997-8-6", "1997-8-7", "1997-8-8", "1997-8-9", "1997-8-10", 
"1997-8-11", "1997-8-12", "1997-8-13", "1997-8-14", "1997-8-15", 
"1997-8-16", "1997-8-17", "1997-8-18", "1997-8-19", "1997-8-20", 
"1997-8-21", "1997-8-22", "1997-8-23", "1997-8-24", "1997-8-25", 
"1997-8-26", "1997-8-27", "1997-8-28", "1997-8-29", "1997-8-30", 
"1997-8-31", "1997-9-1", "1997-9-2", "1997-9-3", "1997-9-4", 
"1997-9-5", "1997-9-6", "1997-9-7", "1997-9-8", "1997-9-9", "1997-9-10", 
"1997-9-11", "1997-9-12", "1997-9-13", "1997-9-14", "1997-9-15", 
"1997-9-16", "1997-9-17", "1997-9-18", "1997-9-19", "1997-9-20", 
"1997-9-21", "1997-9-22", "1997-9-23", "1997-9-24", "1997-9-25", 
"1997-9-26", "1997-9-27", "1997-9-28", "1997-9-29", "1997-9-30", 
"1997-10-1", "1997-10-2", "1997-10-3", "1997-10-4", "1997-10-5", 
"1997-10-6", "1997-10-7", "1997-10-8", "1997-10-9", "1997-10-10", 
"1997-10-11", "1997-10-12", "1997-10-13", "1997-10-14", "1997-10-15", 
"1997-10-16", "1997-10-17", "1997-10-18", "1997-10-19", "1997-10-20", 
"1997-10-21", "1997-10-22", "1997-10-23", "1997-10-24", "1997-10-25", 
"1997-10-26", "1997-10-27", "1997-10-28", "1997-10-29", "1997-10-30", 
"1997-10-31", "1997-11-1", "1997-11-2", "1997-11-3", "1997-11-4", 
"1997-11-5", "1997-11-6", "1997-11-7", "1997-11-8", "1997-11-9", 
"1997-11-10", "1997-11-11", "1997-11-12", "1997-11-13", "1997-11-14", 
"1997-11-15", "1997-11-16", "1997-11-17", "1997-11-18", "1997-11-19", 
"1997-11-20", "1997-11-21", "1997-11-22", "1997-11-23", "1997-11-24", 
"1997-11-25", "1997-11-26", "1997-11-27", "1997-11-28", "1997-11-29", 
"1997-11-30", "1997-12-1", "1997-12-2", "1997-12-3", "1997-12-4", 
"1997-12-5", "1997-12-6", "1997-12-7", "1997-12-8", "1997-12-9", 
"1997-12-10", "1997-12-11", "1997-12-12", "1997-12-13", "1997-12-14", 
"1997-12-15", "1997-12-16", "1997-12-17", "1997-12-18", "1997-12-19", 
"1997-12-20", "1997-12-21", "1997-12-22", "1997-12-23", "1997-12-24", 
"1997-12-25", "1997-12-26", "1997-12-27", "1997-12-28", "1997-12-29", 
"1997-12-30", "1997-12-31", "1998-1-1", "1998-1-2", "1998-1-3", 
"1998-1-4", "1998-1-5", "1998-1-6", "1998-1-7", "1998-1-8", "1998-1-9", 
"1998-1-10", "1998-1-11", "1998-1-12", "1998-1-13", "1998-1-14", 
"1998-1-15", "1998-1-16", "1998-1-17", "1998-1-18", "1998-1-19", 
"1998-1-20", "1998-1-21", "1998-1-22", "1998-1-23", "1998-1-24", 
"1998-1-25", "1998-1-26", "1998-1-27", "1998-1-28", "1998-1-29", 
"1998-1-30", "1998-1-31", "1998-10-1", "1998-10-2", "1998-10-3", 
"1998-10-4", "1998-10-5", "1998-10-6", "1998-10-7", "1998-10-8", 
"1998-10-9", "1998-10-10", "1998-10-11", "1998-10-12", "1998-10-13", 
"1998-10-14", "1998-10-15", "1998-10-16", "1998-10-17", "1998-10-18", 
"1998-10-19", "1998-10-20", "1998-10-21", "1998-10-22", "1998-10-23", 
"1998-10-24", "1998-10-25", "1998-10-26", "1998-10-27", "1998-10-28", 
"1998-10-29", "1998-10-30", "1998-10-31", "1998-11-1", "1998-11-2", 
"1998-11-3", "1998-11-4", "1998-11-5", "1998-11-6", "1998-11-7", 
"1998-11-8", "1998-11-9", "1998-11-10", "1998-11-11", "1998-11-12", 
"1998-11-13", "1998-11-14", "1998-11-15", "1998-11-16", "1998-11-17", 
"1998-11-18", "1998-11-19", "1998-11-20", "1998-11-21", "1998-11-22", 
"1998-11-23", "1998-11-24", "1998-11-25", "1998-11-26", "1998-11-27", 
"1998-11-28", "1998-11-29", "1998-11-30", "1998-12-1", "1998-12-2", 
"1998-12-3", "1998-12-10", "1998-12-11", "1998-12-12", "1998-12-13", 
"1998-12-14", "1998-12-15", "1998-12-16", "1998-12-17", "1998-12-18", 
"1998-12-19", "1998-12-20", "1998-12-21", "1998-12-22", "1998-12-23", 
"1998-12-24", "1998-12-25", "1998-12-26", "1998-12-27", "1998-12-28", 
"1998-12-29", "1998-12-30", "1998-12-31"), Pr = c("0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "12.0", "2.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "1.0", "1.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "13.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"6.0", "2.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "6.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "1.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "6.0", "6.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "9.0", "1.5", "0.0", "0.0", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "6.0", "9.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "4.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "10.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "8.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "30.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "16.0", "0.0", "15.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "3.5", "0.0", "0.0", "11.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "2.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "11.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "2.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "10.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "10.0", "0.0", "6.0", "19.8", 
"27.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"2.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"2.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "1.5", "21.5", "1.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "4.5", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "7.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "1.0", "0.0", "0.0", "30.6", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "6.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"4.5", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", 
"0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0", "0.0"), Tmax = c(21.5, 
22, 25, 16, 17.5, 22, 22.6, 23.5, 22, 22, 21.5, 22, 19, 19.5, 
19, 20, 19.5, 17, 13.5, 12, 14.5, 18, 16.5, 19.5, 21, 20, 13.5, 
16, 20.5, 18.5, 20, 23, 15.5, 16, 18, 19.5, 21.5, 22, 20.5, 15.5, 
18.5, 20.5, 21, 21, 22, 21.5, 22, 23, 25, 24.5, 23.5, 23, 26, 
27, 26.5, 21, 25.6, 25, 25.5, 24.5, 21, 21, 25, 27, 26.5, 24, 
21, 21.5, 25, 20, 28, 26, 26.5, 25, 21, 24, 19, 16, 21, 26, 25.6, 
24.5, 25, 29, 30, 29.5, 25, 19, 26.5, 26, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 29, 34, 25, 26.5, 30, 33.5, 
33.5, 23, 25.5, 28.5, 32, 29, 29.5, 25, 32.5, 36, 35, 35.5, 35.5, 
37, 37, 40, 39.5, 40, 39.5, 39, 39, 41, 41, 40.5, 35, 33, 34, 
35.5, 36.5, 31, 37, 37.5, 36.5, 37.5, 36, 37.5, 39, 40, 35, 40, 
43, 42.5, 45, 46, 42.5, 38.5, 36.5, 41.5, 42, 42, 41.5, 42.5, 
37, 36, 36, 36.5, 39, 41, 40.5, 41.5, 44, 43, 42.5, 42, 41.5, 
39.5, 38, 39.5, 40.5, 38.5, 39, 39, 39.5, 41.5, 37, 33, 33.5, 
35, 37.5, 38.5, 38.5, 38.5, 31.3, 30.2, 31, 36, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 
38.5, 38.5, 39, 40, 39.5, 34, 38, 38.5, 29, 33.5, 36, 37, 40, 
39.5, 39, 40.5, 39, 39, 36.5, 30, 33.5, 38.5, 34, 32, 29, 35.5, 
37, 37.5, 37.5, 38.5, 38, 36, 37, 37, 36, 37.5, 33.5, 35, 35.5, 
35, 35.5, 34, 37, 36, 30, 38, 40, 36, 36.5, 33.5, 35, 37, 35, 
36.5, 37, 35, 34, 30.5, 32, 30.5, 32.5, 30, 30, 30, 32.5, 29, 
31, 32, 30.5, 31, 30.5, 30.5, 29, 29.5, 28, 24.5, 25.5, 26.5, 
18, 16.5, 23.5, 26.5, 28, 23.5, 23.5, 26.5, 26.5, 27, 23, 28.5, 
26.5, 29, 26.5, 27, 26.5, 27.5, 28, 22, 19.5, 22, 24, 26, 23, 
23, 22, 22, 26, 26, 23.5, 25, 25, 25, 22.6, 22.5, 16.5, 15, 18, 
21, 21, 23.5, 21, 20, 19, 21, 21.5, 21.5, 20, 20.5, 20.5, 16, 
16, 13, 14.5, 19, 15.5, 20, 19, 20.5, 19.5, 22, 22, 12, 21.5, 
21, 18, 17, 12.5, 10, 12.5, 15.5, 16, 19, 17, 22, 22.5, 18.5, 
15, 18.5, 21.5, 14, 13.5, 16.5, 17, 9.5, 14, 17, 16.5, 18, 19, 
17.5, 18.5, 17, 17.5, 18.5, 21, 22, 22, 19, 20, 14.5, 14.5, 36.5, 
33.5, 35.3, 34, 35, 34, 35, 35.5, 36, 34, 29.5, 35.5, 35.5, 33.5, 
32, 31.5, 28, 28, 32, 31, 33.5, 35.5, 33, 32.5, 31.5, 31.5, 27, 
30.5, 31, 30.5, 31, 33, 31.5, 29.5, 28, 29, 27, 28.5, 24.5, 28, 
27.5, 30, 29, 27.5, 27, 26.5, 28, 27, 27.5, 28, 27.5, 27, 28.5, 
28.5, 27, 27.5, 27.5, 25.5, 25.5, 27.5, 24.5, 22.5, 26, 25.5, 
25.5, 25, 20, 20.5, 18, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19.5, 10.5, 19.5, 20.5, 
20.5, 19.5, 22.5, 19.5, 21.5, 20.5, 19.5, 21.5, 16.5), Tmin = c(3, 
3, 4.5, 5.5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1.5, 5.5, 
7.5, 2, 2, 2.6, 1, 1.5, 1, 2, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 3, 3.5, 
4, 3, 4, 4.5, 2, 3, 3, 3.5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4.5, 5, 4.5, 4, 6, 6, 
7, 9, 8.5, 9.5, 7, 8, 12, 9, 5.5, 6, 9, 10, 14, 12.5, 13, 12, 
10.5, 8, 9, 9, 12, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 9, 8, 9, 9.5, 11, 10, 11, 
14, 14.5, 14, 12, 10, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18, 19.5, 19, 16.5, 17, 18, 17.5, 13.5, 12, 
15, 18.5, 13.6, 17, 13.5, 16.5, 16.5, 19.5, 19, 18, 19, 19.5, 
20, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5, 23.5, 23.5, 24, 23, 23, 23, 20, 24, 22, 
21.5, 21.5, 23.5, 24.5, 25, 24.5, 23, 25, 25, 24, 24, 25, 25, 
25, 26, 27.5, 22, 22.5, 26, 25.5, 25.5, 26.5, 26.5, 25.5, 26.5, 
25, 24, 25, 26.5, 27.5, 24.5, 26.5, 28, 30, 31, 30, 28.5, 28.5, 
28, 28, 30.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 30, 31, 25.5, 27, 23.5, 25, 27.5, 
28.5, 29, 29, 26.5, 26, 25, 22, 25.5, 23, 24.5, 24.5, 26, 24, 
27.5, 28.6, 28, 28.5, 29, 25.5, 23, 24.5, 25.5, 27.5, 28.5, 28, 
29, 29.5, 28.5, 24, 24, 24, 26, 26, 21.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23, 24, 
25.5, 26.5, 24.5, 26.5, 28, 27.5, 27, 24, 23.5, 24.5, 26, 26, 
23, 23.5, 25.5, 26.5, 22, 24, 24.5, 25, 21, 22, 23, 22.5, 23, 
24, 20, 20, 19, 18.5, 20, 18.5, 20, 19.5, 19, 19.5, 18.5, 18, 
19, 19, 16, 17, 17, 18.5, 17, 16.5, 18, 16.5, 14, 15, 15, 13.5, 
13.5, 13, 14.5, 16.5, 15, 13.5, 13.6, 15, 11.5, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 
12.5, 12, 12, 12, 13, 12.5, 12.5, 9, 9, 6.5, 9, 9.5, 12.5, 9, 
9.5, 7, 7.5, 9, 7, 8, 8, 8.5, 11, 9, 7, 7, 6.5, 5, 5.5, 8.5, 
7.5, 8, 7.5, 6.5, 6.5, 7, 4.5, 5, 8.5, 10, 4.5, 4.6, 7.4, 5.5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5.4, 5, 4, 3.5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.9, 4.9, 
6, 6.5, 6.5, 8.5, 5.5, 5, 5.5, 5.5, 3, 4, 5.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 
0.9, 1, 1.9, 3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 3, 2.9, 4.9, 5.9, 6, 9, 21, 21.5, 
22, 23, 20.5, 21.5, 21, 21.5, 19, 18, 16.5, 14, 16, 16.5, 16.5, 
16, 16.5, 17, 17, 16.5, 15.5, 15.5, 15.5, 14.5, 15, 16, 14.5, 
14, 14, 12.5, 12, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10.5, 11.9, 14.4, 14, 11, 10.5, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 9.5, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 8, 7, 7, 7.5, 7.9, 8, 8, 
7.5, 7.5, 6, 6.5, 5, 5, 6, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3, 
3.5, 3, 2.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 3.5, 2.5, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-482L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are no days with multiple rows and no rows with missingness that have observed values in other columns - what exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to replace a day's missingness with a *different* day's mean?

Comment: @BHudson If 1997-04-01 has a missing value, I would like to replace that NA with the average value of all April 01s in the time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose for each measure, besides date, you'd like to create a modified column that is either that value or in case of an NA, the average for that date. I did this by creating a day column to group by, and then mutating each target column, with ifelse statement, giving value if not NA or average by day if NA.

Your data did not have any days that had NA values for non-date columns with same days, so to test here is modified data:

```
dat <- tibble(
Date = c("1997-4-1", "1997-4-1", "1998-4-1", "1997-4-2"), 
Pr = c(NA, 1, 2, 3), 
Tmax = c(1,NA,3, 3), 
Tmin = c(1,2,3,4))
```

Here is code to modify:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%  
    mutate(day = sub(".*?-", "", Date)) %>% 
    group_by(day) %>% 
    mutate(across(.cols = c(Pr, Tmax, Tmin), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = T), .x), .names = "modified_{.col}"))
```

Here are results. You can ungroup for further processing:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   day [2]
  Date        Pr  Tmax  Tmin day   modified_Pr modified_Tmax modified_Tmin
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 1997-4-1    NA     1     1 4-1           1.5             1             1
2 1997-4-1     1    NA     2 4-1           1               2             2
3 1998-4-1     2     3     3 4-1           2               3             3
4 1997-4-2     3     3     4 4-2           3               3             4
```